# Flutter: Converting latlng position to an address: Setting the address into the textfield

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm trying to convert users latitude and longitude position to address and pass it into a textfield. This is my code below, PLEASE NOTE: THE GEOLOCATOR SERVICE IS NOT INCLUDED HERE. CLICK THIS LINK TO GET THE GEOLOCATOR [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)

```
class LocationInTextField3 extends StatefulWidget {
      const LocationInTextField3({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _LocationInTextFieldState createState() => _LocationInTextFieldState();
    }

    class _LocationInTextFieldState3 extends State<LocationInTextField> {
      TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
        var geolocator = GeolocatorService().determinePosition();
          var Address = "Location";
              late Position position;

      @override
      void initState()  {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        setState(() {
          controller = TextEditingController(text: returnText().toString());

        });
      }
      @override
      void dispose() {
        // TODO: implement dispose
        controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    onTap: () async {
                      Position position = await geolocator;
                      var address = locationInTextField(position);
                      setState(() {

                      });
                    },
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Your location",
                      // prefixIcon: Text("$Address")
                      ),
                    enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                    toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
                        copy: true, cut: true, paste: true, selectAll: true),
                  ),
                  Text("$Address")
                ],
              )),
        );
      }

      returnText() async {
        print(Address);
        // var address = await onTap();
        var address = await onTap();
        print(address);
        setState(() {
        });
        return address;
      }

      Future locationInTextField(Position position) async {
        List<Placemark> placemarks =
        await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        Placemark place = placemarks.first;

        Address = "${place.street}";
        // print(Address);
        setState(() {});
        return Address;
      }
      onTap() async {
        position = await geolocator;
        locationInTextField(position);
      }
    }
```

and this is the error message below and i am adding an image where it shows the address on a text and not in the textfield.

ERROR MESSAGE: I/flutter ( 5045): Instance of 'Future'

[image: screenshot from my emulator]

Thank you and I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use this plugin to convert latitude langitude to address**

```
   geocoding: ^2.0.2

   import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart;
```

**This is the code to convert latlang to address**

```
 List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
    Placemark placeMark = placemarks[0];
     setState(() {
            textController.text = placeMark.toString();
            });
```

**In the placemark you can get the address next step you can set it to text field**

```
var textController = new TextEditingController();
     TextField(
        controller: textController,
        onChanged: (value) {
          
        },
```